# What is the SQL for linking the _DeviceId field in _PushAddress to the SubscriberKey in _Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

We have configured our App to register for mobile push using the SubscriberKey value that exists in Marketing Cloud.  When we view Contact in the Mobile Push channel of All Contacts I can see the SubscriberKey value we used to register the contact in the Contact Key column and the DeviceId(s) in the device ID column but I cannot replicate this view using SQL.

The _PushAddress table has a ContactId field the values for which do not exist in the SubscriberId field of _Subscribers.  I cannot seem to find the link between the value we used to register the device (using the SDK) and the deviceId.

Comment: _subscriber dataview is “all subscribers” from the email channel and may not include the subscribers from the push channel.   But subscriberid = contactid

Comment: Thanks @EazyE, that clarifies a few things which makes me understand that the question I am actually trying to answer is how do I link the ContactID (system set) to the ContactKey (set when registering with the mobile sdk)?  By How do I link - I mean which data extensions do I need to use in SQL to join one to the other?